# How to transcode a PHP array to a JSON array?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

**UPDATE:** Based on suggestions here, I've modified my code. To get a handle on how this works, I am only trying to alert the PHP array with JSON. Still cannot get it to work. The code below resides on the same test.php page. If refreshed, should the alert fire? The function seems to fail as well. The TEST alert does not work.

```
<?php
  header('Content-type: application/json');
  $arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $.getJSON('test.php',function(data) {
      alert("TEST");

      $.each(data, function(key, item) {
        alert(key + item); }); 
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

I am new to JSON and trying to get a PHP array to display in an HTML file. Below is a simple example. Please tell me if this should work and what I am doing wrong. I am trying to output the keys in this array. Thanks.

My PHP script (test.php):

```
     $arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");
json_encode($arr);

$content = file_get_contents('test.htm');
echo $content;
```

My HTML page (test.htm):

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
$.getJSON('test.php',function(data) {
  $.each(data,function(i, item) {
    alert(item.key);
      });
   });
});

 </script>
```

Comment: json is like so `"key":"value"` not `"key"=>"value"`

Comment: If you put the content of a file in test.php, that won't produce the json your javascript expects.

Comment: if you include your test.htm in your test.php, and it calls test.php it's loading itself...

Comment: You still need two pages (in your example) - _test.htm_ which includes the `<script>` tag and the jQuery includes and _test.php_ which as answered just `echo`s the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have included jQuery in your HTML file.

As you are only alerting keys, you don't have to wait for a dom-ready event - and even if you wanted to, I would first get the JSON and put the `$(function...` into the ajax callback.

Your JSON-encoded PHP-array should look like this:

```
{"item1":"test1","item2":"test2","item3":"test3"}
```

Check about this in your debugger, or load test.php directly in your browser. As others have suggested, your PHP code with the `file_get_contents` is a bit odd.

Last, your object traversal won't work. Look at the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/):

```
$.each(data, function(key, item) {
    alert(key + item);
});
```

The string concatenator in JavaScript is the `+`, not the `.` as in PHP. `item.key` would try to access the `key` property of one of your items - none has such one as thy are strings.

Answer (score 2):

It's enought to:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
$arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");
echo json_encode($arr);
exit;
```

Then your $.getJSON will get data.

Answer (score 1):

WHy do you do a file_get_content() of the file which call your php page?

You shouldn't display it, but you should instead display your json data :

```
$arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");
$content = json_encode($arr);

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 1):

No that would not work.

first, make your php echo your array:

```
$arr = array('item1'=>"test1", 'item2'=>"test2", 'item3'=>"test3");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Then call your javascript ajax function, and observe the response

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
$.getJSON('test.php',function(data) {
  $.each(data,function(i, item) {
    alert(item.key);
      });
   });
});
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you don't need to do that last part in php where you call `file_get_contents`.

On your php, you can just do

```
$arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");
echo json_encode($arr);
```

in Javascript, you're going to get back a Javascript object, and a simple way to iterate through the keys is

```
for(var key in data)
{
    alert(key + ' => ' + data[key]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on your PHP script

> json_encode($arr);

is not doing anything, theres no output or saving in a variable

and what is that you are getting from test.htm ? You can't put two different contents in a JSON to be parsed later by the $.getJSON, your PHP script should output ONLY the JSON encoded

try to do this on your PHP code:

```
     $arr = array ('item1'=>"test1",'item2'=>"test2",'item3'=>"test3");
     echo json_encode($arr);
```

and on your Javascript Code do this before just to check:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
 $.get("test.php",function(data){
   var obj = $.parseJSON(data);
   alert("Test 1: " + obj.test1);
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: based on suggestions here, I put all code on one page (test.php) and ran it. Still no alerts. jQuery is being called as well.

Comment: did you put exactly what I sent in your test.php? REMOVE everything from the test.php and put exactly what I sent you in the answer. and tell me what output you got. if you already did that. Access your test.php normally via web browser and copy the output you got when you accessed it and show me.

Comment: The output is the array echo: {"item1":"test1","item2":"test2","item3":"test3"}

Comment: I edited my answer, now replace the javascript you have for this one I sent you.

Comment: Still no alert. Could it be my jQuery call? http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js

Comment: just to be sure if theres nothing wrong with your JQuery, put this code in your javascript: $(function() { alert("working"); });   , if you got the "working" alert, it's working, in case not, there's some error in your code, so you should make a new file only with the basic to see if the JQuery works.

Comment: the alert is working inside the script tag and inside $function(), but the function does not return data.

Answer (score 0):

For those who still lost:

I was using "$.post" to send some data and retrieve info. When using that, my JSON return was coming like a string.

Solution:
Use the 4th parameter **dataType** as **json**.

(Accordingly to http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/).

eg.:

```
$.post('http://SOMEWHERE.COM/A/B/C',
   { 
     parameter:value
   },
   function (data) {
     // success
   },
   'json'
);
```